# Quiz change cell backgrounds according to correct or wrong

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i'm trying to make a quiz, so when u click on the `nextButton` it will check whether the question is correct and if it is it should make the cell green and if it wrong it should make the `chosenCell` red and the `correctCell` green. However it seem to keep reseting the label and not making the cells correct colors. Here is a example when i'm choosing the correct one. it makes the textColor of the first cell white and reset label of the correct?

**Illustration**

[image]

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionCell


        cell.titleLabel.text = options[indexPath.row]



        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("NextCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NextCell

        if colorCheck > 186 {

            cell.nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: quizObject!.navButtonsColor)
        } else {
            cell.nextButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(rgba: quizObject!.navBarColor)
        }


        cell.nextButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        cell.nextButton.addTarget(self, action: "done", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        return cell
    }


}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath and done**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
   chosenIndex = indexPath.row
}


func done() {
    if chosenIndex != nil {

            tableView?.deselectRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: chosenIndex!, inSection: 0), animated: true)

            let cell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: chosenIndex!, inSection: 0)) as! QuestionCell
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        let cell2 = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: correctIndex, inSection: 0)) as! QuestionCell
        cell2.titleLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()


        if chosenIndex! == correctIndex {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            cell2.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        }


        tableView?.reloadData()

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off: you are misusing the dequeuing mechanism. If you want to get an already existing cell, use

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Secondly you should never manipulate the cell from anywhere else than the inside the `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)`. The reason for that is that if the UITableView decides to reload its content all changes done solely outside the above method will be lost.

What you have to instead is changing the backing state and manually reload the affected rows.

You have to change your current logic there to be something like

```
if indexPath.section == 0 {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ButtonCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuestionCell

    cell.titleLabel.text = options[indexPath.row]

    if let chosen = chosenIndex {
        if chosen == indexPath.row {
            if indexPath.row == correctIndex {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            }
        } else {
            if indexPath.row == correctIndex {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
            } else {
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
        }
    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

In your `func done()` you then only have to tell the `tableView` the correct rows:

- the selected and correct one if the correct cell has been selected
- the selected cell and the correct cell if the selection was wrong

Note that I left out setting the textColor properties since their logic is similar to the backgroundColor and I think you can and should figure out how to set them correctly accordingly.

Comment: but i want to trigger this when i click on `nextButton` in section 1

Comment: @PeterPik I do not understand: it does not matter at what point in time you want to call it.

Comment: @PeterPik did it work for you? In general it would be kind of you to leave upvotes on the helpful answer rewarding the answerer - looking at your previous questions shows that you rarely do that.